# ARD Unix Command Help - Answer Yes? - Automate Domain Unjoin / Rejoin

Tags: terminal, active-directory, remote-desktop

We had a bunch of Macs come up with no network access this morning, and unjoining and rejoining the domain fixes that. I'm trying to make this as automated as possible.

The following works great from Terminal with "yes | sudo sh myscript.sh", but I'm not sure how to make the UNIX Command answer yes when prompted when it says "Computer account already exists! Bind to Existing? (y/n):"

Here's what I have, and any advice is appreciated:

```
domain="mydomain"

username="myusername" password="mypassword"

olddomain=$( dsconfigad -show | awk '/Active Directory Domain/{print $NF}' ) computername=$( scutil --get ComputerName ) adcomputerid=$( echo "${computername}" | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] ) prefix="${adcomputerid:0:6}"

dsconfigad -remove -force -u "${username}" -p "${password}"

dsconfigad -add "${domain}" -username "${username}" -password "${password}"
```

---

Comment: Have you tried adding `-f` to the `dsconfigad` call to force the operation (shouldn't ask for user input)?

Comment: This guy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The full answer would be:

```
# ...
dsconfigad -add "${domain}" -force -username "${username}" -password "${password}"
```

The `-force` forces the action (skips asking for user confirmation).

Relevant portion of the helptext below:

```
$ dsconfigad
Usage: dsconfigad -add domain -username value [-computer value] [-force]
                  [-password value] [-ou dn] [-preferred server]
                  [-localuser value] [-localpassword value]

# ...

  -force                force the process (i.e., join the existing account)

# ...
```